# I am unable to revoke insert privilege in oracle database as its again inserting data into table though I revoked it

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am unable to revoke insert privilege in oracle database as I revoked it on table though it is inserting data into table.

> ```
> SQL> REVOKE INSERT ON VENKI.T1 FROM VENKI;
>
> Revoke succeeded.
>
> SQL> REVOKE ALL ON VENKI.T1 FROM VENKI;
>
> Revoke succeeded.
>
> SQL> show user
> USER is "SYS"
>
> SQL> INSERT INTO VENKI.T1 VALUES(10);
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Comment: The SYS user bypassed all privileges if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

You are connected as SYS and performed INSERT. As it *owns* the database, it can do anything.

Besides, you revoked insert from user VENKI (not from SYS) which is useless anyway because table owner can also do whatever it wants with its own tables. Why would you prevent owner from inserting?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot revoke the privileges of the owner of an object.